# Animated Gifs on sharepoint roll up images and content query/search web parts

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part, sharepoint-on-prem, image-display, rollup-image

Any reason why when using a content query or search to pull roll up images (animated gifs) from article pages they do not animate?

Any workaround?

Comment: Is it not so that gif:s need to at exactly the "correct" size for them to animate in some cases? Not sure if that is the issue here, or if SP actually "unanimates" them

Comment: The rollup image is by default 100x100 (originally the image is 200x200 since it is supposed to be only an icon in the content search. I have noticed it does animate when building the entry with the rollup image (rollup image field) but not later. Is it a problem of the content query? Of course animated gifs do animate in normal pages (wiki page, body of article pages etc)

Comment: there is no documentation on the matter anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I added animated gif to my news as rollup image and it works but it shouldn't be Rendention Image..

Also animation works in content search webpart, but also, it shouldn't have rendition in querystring

bad: /PublishingImages/Test%20Photo%20Galerija/insptilesani4.gif?RenditionID=2

good: /PublishingImages/Test%20Photo%20Galerija/insptilesani4.gif